# How to show SVM plot with several features in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, svm, matlab-figure

I have 100 samples with 16 features each, and I want to plot the SVM results, but from what I understand that the below code, takes only two columns from X, (two features), is there a way to have the SVM results with all features in one plot?

```
figure;
hgscatter = gscatter(X(:,1),X(:,2), Y);
hold on;
h_sv = plot(svmModel.SupportVectors(:,1), svmModel.SupportVectors(:,2) , 'ko', 'markersize', 8);
% X : features, Y : lables
```

Answer (score 0):

Visualizing high dimensional spaces is more of an art than a science.  You might try [clustergram](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/examples/working-with-the-clustergram-function.html) or similar plots (green could be a high value in each feature and red a low value).  Dimensionality reduction (e.g., supervised PCA, tSNE, etc. might be other options).